# What brain areas are involved in memorizing sections of a song?

Tags: perception, cognitive-neuroscience, memory, music

Typically when I listen to a song, the song will have different sections (e.g. chorus, verses, etc). As a composer, I have found that many songs use this structure to create a sense of repetition and help make the song more familiar to the listener. It tends to give the song a cohesiveness that simply introducing new material over and over doesn't yield.

Therefore, when I listen to a song, what brain area helps me  remember parts of the song so when I hear them again, they sound familiar?

**Example:**

> We Wish You A Merry Christmas

Answer (score 5):

I would read [this paper](http://www.stefan-koelsch.de/papers/TICS2005_towards-a-neural-basis-of-music-perception.pdf), its mighty interesting.

**Books**

[Snyder, B.(2000) Music and memory: An introduction. The MIT Press. Cambridge 291.](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/music-and-memory)

**Hemispheric Coordination and Conflict**

> "...while listening to the melody of the popular carol "Silent Night", the
>   right hemisphere thinks, "Ah, yes, Silent Night", while the left
>   hemisphere thinks, "two sequences: the first a literal repetition, the
>   second a repetition at different pitch levels—ah, yes, Silent Night by
>   Franz Gruber, typical pastorate folk style." The brain for the most
>   part works well when each hemisphere performs its own function while
>   solving a task or problem; the two hemispheres are quite
>   complementary. However, situations arise when the two modes are in
>   conflict, resulting in one hemisphere interfering with the operation
>   of the other hemisphere." (Regalski 1977)

**Melodic Memory**

> "Performance was greatest for the musicians, particularly for the
>   nontonal melody pairs. These differences were not primarily
>   attributable to pitch discrimination or pitch working memory
>   impairments. The findings point to differential contributions of the
>   left and right mesial temporal lobes to melodic memory, with
>   specificity of the right mesial temporal lobe emerging for melodic
>   learning within a tonal musical context." (Wilson, Saling 2008)

**Tonal Memory**

> In general, tonal memory is supported by a wide network including
>   primary and secondary auditory areas more right lateralized, the
>   supramarginal gyrus particularly on the left, and dorsolateral
>   inferior frontal areas, more clearly seen under heavy memory load
>   conditions (Zatorre et al., 1994; Griffith et al., 1999; Gaab et al.,
>   2003). Premotor areas, the cerebellum, basal ganglia and the thalamus
>   are activated when subvocal tonal rehearsal is explicitly required
>   (Hickok et al., 2003; Koelsch et al., 2009). Importantly a direct
>   comparison of memory for verbal syllables and sung pitches under
>   rehearsal and under suppression elicited largely overlapping brain
>   areas consistent with this network (Schulze et al., 2011).

Quoted from [this](http://journal.frontiersin.org/article/10.3389/fpsyg.2013.00712/full) source.

---

**Sources**

[Who Knows Where Music Lurks in the Mind of Man? New Brain Research Has The Answer.](http://mej.sagepub.com/content/63/9/31.full.pdf) 
*Journal of Music Educators* (May 1977, Vol.63, pages 31-38)

[Contribution of the left and right Mesial Temporal Lobes to Musical Memory: Evidence from melodic learning difficulties](http://mp.ucpress.edu/content/25/4/33.full-text.pdf+html) 
Sarah J. Wilson, Michael M. Saling 
*Music Perception: An Interdisciplinary Journal*, Vol. 25 No. 4, April 2008; (pp. 303-314)

[￼Towards A Neural Basis Of Music Perception.](http://www.stefan-koelsch.de/papers/TICS2005_towards-a-neural-basis-of-music-perception.pdf) 
Stefan Koelsch and Walter A. Siebel 
*Trends in Cognitive Sciences* Vol.9 No.12 December 2005

[Functional anatomy of pitch memory—an fMRI study with sparse temporal sampling.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1053811903002246) 
Gaab, N., Gaser, C., Zaehle, T., Jancke, L., and Schlaug, G. (2003). 
*Neuroimage* 19, 1417–1426.

[Neural mechanisms underlying melodic perception and memory for pitch.](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/14/4/1908.long) 
Zatorre, R. J., Evans, A. C., and Meyer, E. (1994).
*J. Neurosci.* 14, 1908–1919.

[Auditory-motorinteraction revealed by fMRI: speech, music, and working memory in area](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?Db=pubmed&Cmd=ShowDetailView&TermToSearch=12965041) 
Hickok, G., Buchsbaum, B., Humphries, C., and Muftuler, T. (2003).
*Spt. J. Cogn. Neurosci.* 15, 673–682.

[Functional architecture of verbal and tonal working memory: an FMRI study.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?Db=pubmed&Cmd=ShowDetailView&TermToSearch=18330870)
Koelsch, S., Schulze, K., Sammler, D., Fritz, T., Müller, K., and Gruber, O. (2009). 
*Hum. Brain Mapp.* 30, 859–873.

[Neuroarchitecture of verbal and tonal working memory in nonmusicians and musicians.](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/hbm.21060/abstract;jsessionid=FEC430A5D259F49F25442A0C23BABE77.f02t01) 
Schulze, K., Zysset, S., Mueller, K., Friederici, A. D., and Koelsch, S. (2011).
 *Hum. Brain Mapp.* 32, 771–783.

Comment: Not all those sources are incorporated in your answer. I would only list those you refer to, or disambiguate between 'other' potentially relevant papers, and the ones you provided a summary/reference of.

Comment: Those are the papers mentioned within the sources I've quoted. They are not necessarily the sources themselves. Note that the last source has 6 citations that I have directly linked to.